# Speeding Up a Function Involving String Searches

Tags: string, common-lisp, destructuring, sbcl

I have one function that profiling shows consumes most of the run time. Is there perhaps a way to rethink this for a substantial speedup? (Running Common Lisp in SBCL)

```
(defun compatible-words (option1 option2)
  ;Determines if two field+word fillings are compatible.
  (destructuring-bind (field1 word1) option1
    (destructuring-bind (field2 word2) option2
      (destructuring-bind (index1 index2) (or (gethash (list field1 field2) *crosscuts-ht*)
                                              '(nil nil))
        (or (null index1) (char= (schar word1 index1) (schar word2 index2)))))))
```

(ps: Adding declarations seems to have minimal effects.)

Edit: Sorry about not providing some context for analysis. Option1 & option2 are 2-item lists of a symbol and a simple-string. String length is a max of ~50 uppercase alphabetic chars, with an average of ~7 chars. Thus index1 & index2 can be fixnums, and `*crosscuts-ht*` is an #'equal hashtable with keys as lists of 2 symbols. Hashtable values are lists of the 2 indexes.

Comment: It's difficult to optimize a function that just destructures, gethash and do 1 comparison, without knowing what calls it and how it calls it. And without having the declaration of *crosscuts-ht*. I guess you defined *crosscuts-ht* with :test #'equalp ?

Comment: Do you have a maximum size limit for your strings ? do you have constraints on what fields are? is there a constant list of fields? maybe you can add more details about your constraints to help with data representation (e.g. index1 and index2 could be two 16bit integers packed in a 32bit integer, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strings have a size of at most 50, you can round that to 64, ie. 6 bits (or 8 bits, something most architectures are more optimized to access), making the pair of indices fit in 12 bits (resp. 16).

If each field is a symbol, you could maybe associate a single index to it at creation time, e.g. in its `symbol-value`, from 0 to N. And your lookup table could be an `NxN` matrix of `(unsigned-byte 12)` or `(unsigned-byte 16)` integers.

This may improve your lookup time.

If the list of symbols grows dynamically, is too large and/or the matrix is sparse, you probably want to keep the hash-table.

Comment: Interesting idea. The field symbols don't change in each run, and the max matrix size would be only a little over 1000 entries. They would be rather sparse at an average of about 15%, but that's no problem. As I'm (currently) unfamiliar with byte manipulations, can you show how to pack and unpack a couple of nonnegative fixnums into (unsigned-byte 16)? Also, since space is not an issue, is there a major time advantage of using byte entries over a simple dotted list of two fixnum indices? Thanks.

Comment: @davypough you would need to use DDB (resp. LPB) to pack (resp. unpack) the integers. For example: `(dpb 3 (byte 8 8) (dpb 5 (byte 8 0) 0))` is `#b0000001100000101`; you could also use ASH and LOGIOR like `<<` and `|` in C `(logior (ash 3 8) 5)`

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun compatible-words (option1 option2)
  (destructuring-bind (index1 index2) (gethash (list (car option1) (car option2)) *crosscuts-ht* '(nil nil))
    (or (null index1) (char= (schar (cadr option1) index1) 
                             (schar (cadr option2) index2)))))
```

I eliminated 2 destructuring binds by using `car` and `cadr` instead.
Without having to test it it is clear that `car` nd `cadr` will be faster since super cheap.
I eliminated one `or` by giving `'(nil nil)` as default to `gethash`.

Further, you could type `index` to gain speed:

```
(defun compatible-words (option1 option2)
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0))
           (type fixnum index1 index2))
  (multiple-value-bind (index1 index2) (gethash (list (cadr option1) (cadr option2)) *crosscuts-ht* '(nil nil))
    (or (null index1)
        (char= (schar option1 index1)
               (schar option2 index2))))))
```

Comment: It should be faster, *in theory*. It would be nice to compare timings, because implementations optimize code sometimes in an unintuitive manner.

Comment: I'm getting some unintuitive testing results here. First, running your algorithmic improvements with and without declarations produces negligible timing differences (within ~1%) on SBCL. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like SBCL does a good job of optimizing without any declarations at all.

Comment: Second, comparing your version with mine--but changing your multiple-value-bind to destructuring-bind, and gethash default to (-1 -1)--I again get minimal variation (but yours is about ~2% faster). I guess my conclusion is that tinkering is, more often than not, ineffective, at least in SBCL. The best time is spent on rethinking the algorithm. Agree or disagree?

Comment: @davypough I agree. I didn't expect huge gains from this.